# ImageIcon not loading

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

So I am trying to make a small game for a project in college. I have an image class that loads the images etc. I know this class works because I tested it all when I made it. But then I decided to use a form maker, in this case WindowsBuilder Pro to make a form that was better then I could code. I am now trying to call a function that in theory will load call the images class and load the image then add that image as an imageicon to a label within a jPanel. But I am getting nothing. Any help?

```
    private void loadres(){
    String PROGRAM_DIRECTORY = "E:/WordGame/bin/Images/";

    Functions.Resources rs = new Functions.Resources();
    rs.loadResources();
    Functions.ImageLib iL = rs.getIL();

    try {
        BGImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(iL.mergeImages(iL.getImageArray(0),iL.getImage(PROGRAM_DIRECTORY + "Astroid1Image.png"))));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BGImage.revalidate();
    BGImage.repaint();
}
```

And here is the Image functions I am using:

```
public class ImageLib {

private ArrayList<BufferedImage> BIArray = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

public ImageLib(){  
}

public BufferedImage getImage(String ref){
    BufferedImage Bi = null;

    try{
        Bi = ImageIO.read(new File(ref));
    }catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Bi;
}

public BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage Bi, int nW, int nH){
    int w = Bi.getWidth();
    int h = Bi.getHeight();

    BufferedImage nBi = new BufferedImage(nW, nH, Bi.getType());
    Graphics2D g = nBi.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

    g.drawImage(Bi,0,0,nW,nH,0,0,w,h,null);
    g.dispose();

    return nBi;
}

public void addToArray(BufferedImage img){
    BIArray.add(img);
}

public BufferedImage getImageArray(int index){
    return (BufferedImage) BIArray.get(index);
}

public BufferedImage mergeImages(BufferedImage I1, BufferedImage I2) throws IOException{
    int w = Math.max(I1.getWidth(), I2.getWidth()); 
    int h = Math.max(I1.getHeight(), I2.getHeight()); 
    BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 

    Graphics g = combined.getGraphics(); 
    g.drawImage(I1, 0, 0, null); 
    g.drawImage(I2, 0, 0, null); 
    g.dispose();

    return combined;
}
```

}

Comment: Might help to tell you that the layout for the frame/panel is grouplayout, and that the BGImage was a label I added in the WYSIWUG editor WBP. The Label is width 501, height 250 or something close.

Comment: Put your images in your src folder and try this ^^:
ClassLoader cldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

java.net.URL imageURL   = cldr.getResource("path/to/your/images/picture.gif");
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @eureka Thanks for adding the answer.  Note that I only get notified if you start comments with `@Andrew`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer ^^

```
ClassLoader cldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader(); 
java.net.URL imageURL = cldr.getResource("path/to/your/images/picture.gif"); 
ImageIcon  imgIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, and give me the path to the file easier but it still isnt rendering the image. The issue isn't how to get the image but that it isn't rendering it.

Comment: @Tempus35 Here is my code that I used with JFrame;
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/eproject/dcl/images/lock.png"));
setIconImage(imgIcon.getImage());